# Can't populate a drop down box via jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Background Information

I have some PHP / HTML / JavaScript code that loads a web form. For discussion purposes, let's say this form is the "edit widget details" page. 
This form contains a table... with a bunch of rows. Each row has one drop down box - the same one for each row - and the selected value of the drop down is determined based on previously saved data in the database.

**Problem**

The drop down lists are not being populated by the .append() call that I'm making and I don't know why.

**Code**

Here's the sequence of events in my logic:

1. PHP logic - loops through each record that needs to be included in the table... and creates an EMPTY  box like so:

   ```
     for ($i=0; $i < count($w_details['tc']); $i++) {      
         ....
        //logic to build basic table structure including:
        echo "<td><select placeholder='Domain:' name='domain" .$i ."' id=domain" .$i ."'></select></td>";

        echo "<input type='hidden' class='domainvals' id='hidden_domain" .$i . "' name='hidden_domain" .$i. "' value='" .$wdetails['tc'][$i]['destdomain'] . "'/>"; 
        ...
     }
   ```

Then once the page is finished rendering, I have this logic in my document.ready section:

```
    //populate domain list.
    $.ajax({
          url:"<?php echo site_url('domain/domainlist');?>",
          type:'POST',
          dataType:'json',
          success: function(res) {
                //loop through results
                var htmlstring = "<option value='' disabled selected>Select the Domain</option>";
                for (var key in res) {
                    if (res.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                            htmlstring += "<option value=" + res[key]['domain'] + ">" + res[key]['domain'] + "</option>";
                    }
                 }
                 //find every hidden input that is storing a domain value
                 $('.domainvals').each(function (i, row) {
                    console.log($(this).val()) ;
                    $('#domain'+i).append(htmlstring);
                    //TODO:  add logic to select the right value using $this.val();
                  });

          }, 
          error: function(xhr, req, err) {
                 //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                 console.log(err.Message);
          }
    });
```

**What I've Tried so far:**

In the F12 debug window, I've verified that  I have a "domain0" control like this:

```
    $("#domain0").find('option')
```

No error messages appear (just the empty array / list) so I definitely have created it. I can also see the controls on the form.

I tried to change my code that appends the html to hard code the name, like so:

```
  $('#domain0').append(htmlstring);
```

Again, no errors, but it doesn't populate the list.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I'm sure it's something simple that I'm just missing.

Comment: Because the html has been dynamically added jquery selector probably can't find it in the DOM. Try something like: `$(document).find('#domain0').append(htmlstring)`

Comment: What I don't understand is that you're using ajax to populate the form once the document has finished loading. However, PHP can do this very easily as well `json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to/file.json'), true)`. I suggest to only bind user events to ajax requests.

Comment: @bos570, hm... the html to create the basic select isn't dynamic.  Just the options for the list are queried via jquery

Comment: @Happydevdays yes, but because he is targeting the elements through dynamically added html wouldn't that make a difference?

Comment: @bos570 i tried changing the code to do what you suggested and I'm still having the same problem.  No errors anywhere though...

Comment: Just to get to the root of the problem can you do something like `$('#domain0').on('click', function(){ console.log('Clicked') });` and tell me if you get 'clicked' consoled

Comment: @Xorifelse i think you make a good comment.  I'm going to revisit the entire page so that I no longer use ajax for things that the server can do right off the top.

Comment: In your PHP code, on your first echo, you are missing a single quote before domain where it says id='domain' which may be causing the id not to show on your selects.

Comment: What do you see if you do `$("#domain0")` in the debug window?

Answer (score 0):

You can append an option using Javascript/Jquery like this:

```
$('myDropDown').append($('<option>', {
    value: optionValue,
    text: optionText
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding those domain

> $("#domain(n)")

elements dynamically, then you cannot just access them like

```
$("#domain0")
```

do

```
$(document).find("#domain0") or $("body").find("#domain0")
```

instead.